# How to read the stripe webhook response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coldfusion, stripe-payments

I have created the coldfusion file to catch the STRIPE webhook response.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="headerdump">
    <cfdump var="#toString(getHttpRequestData().content, 'utf-8')#" expand="yes" format="text">
</cfsavecontent>
```

When i print the headerdump, got the below response. I want to extract the node values of the output text.

```
<pre>{
  "id": "evt_1041EO45YXiN2y2zPhZbNrgh",
  "created": 1399872268,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "invoice.payment_succeeded",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "date": 1399872268,
      "id": "in_1041EO45YXiN2y2zQF1xhLyl",
      "period_start": 1399872268,
      "period_end": 1399872268,
      "lines": {
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 1,
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/invoices/in_1041EO45YXiN2y2zQF1xhLyl/lines",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "sub_41EOmzNFelCyAL",
            "object": "line_item",
            "type": "subscription",
            "livemode": false,
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "usd",
            "proration": false,
            "period": {
              "start": 1399872268,
              "end": 1399958668
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "plan": {
              "interval": "month",
              "name": "test one day",
              "created": 1399536505,
              "amount": 500,
              "currency": "usd",
              "id": "test_001",
              "object": "plan",
              "livemode": false,
              "interval_count": 1,
              "trial_period_days": 1,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "statement_description": "half day trial"
            },
            "description": null,
            "metadata": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "subtotal": 0,
      "total": 0,
      "customer": "cus_41EOvhzjYGx7ci",
      "object": "invoice",
      "attempted": true,
      "closed": true,
      "paid": true,
      "livemode": false,
      "attempt_count": 0,
      "amount_due": 0,
      "currency": "usd",
      "starting_balance": 0,
      "ending_balance": null,
      "next_payment_attempt": null,
      "charge": null,
      "discount": null,
      "application_fee": null,
      "subscription": "sub_41EOmzNFelCyAL",
      "metadata": {
      },
      "description": null
    }
  },
  "object": "event",
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": "iar_41EO1vDF1gpnPn"
}</pre>
```

Please suggest how to read this either in coldfusion or javascript.

Thanks

Comment: @Peter: I have tried but got error "JSON parsing failure at character 1:'<' in". Also tried with remove <pre> tags, but again same error with next character.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to try and extract the JSON from your string

Comment: Don't use `<cfdump>` to generate the content. It will most likely add unwanted content to your variable. Just use `#toString(getHttpRequestData().content, 'utf-8')#` within the `<cfsavecontent>` tags and see if that works better.

Comment: Beyond the cfdump issue that Miguel highlights (there is no need for cfdump nor cfsavecontent here), this question is basically the same thing as the linked one (if there is any significant difference edit the question with suitable details and it can be re-opened).

Answer (score 2):

I do something like this:

```
<cfscript>
  variables.requestdata = getHTTPRequestData();
  variables.sStripeData = toString(variables.requestdata.content);
  variables.stStripeData  = deserializeJSON(variables.sStripeData);
</cfscript>
```